# Refine a SQL query for getting count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I have the following query that gets some results I would like to group by attribute 'state'.
I tried different subquery but they didn't work and I'm a bit blocked.
The SQL is:

```
    SELECT state, id_candidate_basic, MAX( DATE )  FROM `candidate_state` 
    WHERE `date` <= '2013-09-06 00:00:00' GROUP BY id_candidate_basic
    ORDER BY `candidate_state`.`id_candidate_basic` DESC
```

This returns currently:

[image]

I would get a count(*) for each state. Example:
F, 14
I, 10
O, 9

Comment: wouldnt you just order by state then by ID?

Comment: This is because I have more instances for each id_candidate_basic. Example: 
F - 1080 - 2013.09.03
O - 1080 - 2013.09.03

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  state, 
        id_candidate_basic, 
        MAX( DATE ),
        COALESCE(totalCount, 0) totalCount
FROM    `candidate_state` 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  state, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    candidate_state
            WHERE   `date` <= '2013-09-06 00:00:00' 
            GROUP   BY state
        )   ON candidate_state.state = b.state
WHERE   `date` <= '2013-09-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP   BY id_candidate_basic
ORDER   BY `candidate_state`.`id_candidate_basic` DESC
```